# How can I simulate same behavior as history.push("/Initial"); using hash router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

I had to modify from:

```
   <Provider store={store}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Header />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </I18nextProvider>
      </Provider>
```

to:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
              <HashRouter>
                <Header />
                <Main />
                <Footer />
              </HashRouter>
            </I18nextProvider>
          </Provider>
```

I made the change to avoid 404 error when refreshing the page, and to avoid the same error when an activation url is sent from an email

Now, the code below does not work

```
history.push("/Drawer");
```

How I can do the same thing but using hashrouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// install react-router-dom
npm i react-router-dom

// import withRouter in your Component
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// now you can use
// in class component
this.props.history.push('/Drawer');
// in function component
props.history.push('/Drawer');

// export your component
// without connect
export default withRouter(YourComponent);
// with connect
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent));
```

Comment: Provide Drawer Component in Question.